# How to make custom post meta wp_editor translatable?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have custom post type named *soto_property* in which I have added three *wp_editor* as post meta, using this code -

```
 wp_editor( htmlspecialchars_decode($valueeee1),
               'propertyEditor1',
               $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'detail',
                                 'editor_class'=>'propertyEditor')
              );

    wp_editor( htmlspecialchars_decode($valueeee2),
               'propertyEditor2',
               $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'features',
                                 'editor_class'=>'propertyEditor')
              );

    wp_editor( htmlspecialchars_decode($valueeee3),
               'propertyEditor3',
               $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'text_to_pdf',
                                 'editor_class'=>'propertyEditor')
              );
```

Now I have installed `qtranslate` plugin to make my site Multilingual. This plugin automaticaly add Language tab in its default content editor. I want to add these languages tabs in my custom editor also, so it can save content in defined languages.

How can I do this.? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter('soto_property','qtrans_convertURL');
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to define translatable strings. [Check this page in codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) for more details.

Updated code should look like this:

```
$settings = array('textarea_name'=>__('detail', 'your-text-domain'),
                  'editor_class'=>'propertyEditor')
```

If it won't work for you, try the [following trick](http://tonykwon.com/2010/07/09/how-to-enable-qtranslate-meta-on-custom-post-types/).

Here's a code snippet from the last link:

```
if ( is_admin() &&  function_exists("qtrans_getSortedLanguages") ) {
    add_action('admin_menu', 'enable_qTranslate_Meta');
}
function enable_qTranslate_Meta() {
    global $qtransMETA;

    $post_types = get_post_types();
    /* post and page types are already processed by the plugin */
    $disabled_types = array( 'post', 'page', 'attachment', 'revision', 'nav_menu_item' );
    $enabled_types  = array_diff( $post_types, $disabled_types );

    if ( $enabled_types ) {
            foreach( $enabled_types as $enabled_type ) {
                    add_meta_box(
                            'qtrans_meta_meta_box', //HTML id
                            __('Multilingual META', 'qtranslate-meta'), //title
                            array(&$qtransMETA, 'meta_box_generate'), //callback
                            $enabled_type, //type
                            'normal', //context - normal, advanced, side
                            'high' //priority - high, low
                    );
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I have used qranslate-x plugin which makes my custom wp_editor translatable on my custom post type page.